# Display Custom Meta data in DIVI

Tags: wordpress, metadata, divi

I know this requires customization but cant figure out where to edit .

I have created one Custom field using ACF (Advanced Custom Fields). I want it to show up in my blog meta data (not on the page). DIVI has author,date,comment,rating,category.

ACF has a function where i can call the value $value = get_field( "text_field" );.I know it can be added in the child theme function.php but need help with the coding.

below link shows how to add "last updated" to my meta data . i need to replace it with the custom field

[add "last updated" to meta](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/divi-resources/how-to-add-the-last-updated-date-to-divis-blog-post-meta-data)

[meta image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2WN9.jpg)

Edit :
I managed to achieve it by editing my child theme, i used the meta_key to display the value from my custom category. i added the code to the array which displayed the meta data. (module-posts-content.php)

'meta_key'       => $value = the_field('custom_date_or_text'),

One final problem is my custom field appears above the meta fields rather than in line with it .

(code from my theme)

```
<?php
                    $meta_args = array(
                        'author_link'    => $show_author,
                        'author_link_by' => et_get_safe_localization( __( 'Posted by %s', 'extra' ) ),
                        'post_date'      => $show_date,
                        'date_format'    => $date_format,
                        'categories'     => $show_categories,
                        'comment_count'  => $show_comments,
                        'rating_stars'   => $show_rating,
                        'meta_key'       => $value = the_field('custom_date_or_text'),
                    );
                    ?>
```

[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMQCq.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! _blog meta data (not on the page)_ What does this mean? Are you trying to `update_post_meta`? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/

Comment: Divi has a built in option called dynamic content to display custom fields inside a post or page. I want the meta to be displayed on my blog module or feature post slide module. I am guessing I will have to edit my child theme. The image attached has a reference as to where I require the meta to show

Comment: I'm very familiar with Divi. The dynamic content does not get pulled into the blog/post slide module. You won't be able to use your child theme for this. You will need to create a custom Blog and Featured Post Slide Module since the modules don't offer any WP filters to hook into.

Comment: thank you for your time, i managed to display my custom field by using the child theme. one final thing is i need it to align with my meta data, it shows up above the default metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Try fetching the post_meta along with the ID on that post/page template:

```
<?php $text_field = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'text_field', true); ?>

<p><?php echo esc_html( $text_field );?></p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am guessing that this code will fetch my custom metada into a post or page. Divi has a built in option called dynamic content.  I want the meta to be displayed on my blog module or feature post slide module. I am guessing I will have to edit my child theme. The image attached  has a reference